# wordpress migration: Uppercase redirect

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I'm migrating my site to wordpress . The old CMS uses uppercase characters for post urls (wordpress doesn't) . Is there any way to redirect 301 the old urls with uppercase characters to lowercase ? I don't want to do it manual, because i have more than 5000 posts .

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be to put some redirect rules into your .htaccess file. This link shows you how to redirect all uppercase URLS to lowercase:

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase.html

(This link also shows you a quicker way, if you have access to your server's httpd.conf file, but most shared hosting solutions don't, so the .htaccess thing should sort you out)